# Is there a wildcard-sort functionality of making the internals visible to assemblies that matches the common assembly name?

Tags: .net

Is there a wildcard-sort of functionality for making the internals visible to assemblies that share common assembly's *major*(My english-fu is failing me)  name?

For example, `The.Empire` is the major name of all assemblies. I tried `The.Empire.*`, but to no avail.

Assembly A

```
[assembly: System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InternalsVisibleTo("The.Empire.*")]


namespace The.Empire
{
    internal static class Constants
    {
        internal readonly static string CommonId = "Luke";
    }
}
```

Assembly B

```
namespace The.Empire.Strikes
{
    public class Mate
    {
        public void AccessSomething()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", Constants.CommonId); // inaccessible
        }
    }
}
```

Assembly C

```
namespace The.Empire.Back
{
    public class Mate
    {
        public void AccessSomething()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", Constants.CommonId); // inaccessible
        }
    }
}
```

Is this possible? On OOP inheritance analogy, something analogous to `protected`, only the deriver has access to protected

It's not a loose coupling if I put the specific assembly name on InternalsVisibleTo. Other implementors of Assembly A can't be catered unless I recompile AssemblyA

```
[assembly: System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InternalsVisibleTo("The.Empire.Strikes")]
[assembly: System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InternalsVisibleTo("The.Empire.Back")]
```

Comment: `internal` is designed to reduce potential for coupling on implementation details. `InternalsVisibleTo` is designed to relax that restriction for strongly related assemblies - code that should have its own assembly, but is still strongly coupled to the other assembly.  What you're describing doesn't match that pattern.  What is the higher level goal you are trying to solve?  It is possible that other techniques could work better for you (e.g. still keeping your definitions internal, but exposing it to the consuming code as source files, not assemblies - build version constants for example)

Comment: I'd also have a use case: I have several unit test projects and instead of specifying each assembly individually, I'd just like to have "MyNamespace.*.UnitTests".

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx) suggests that the only ways to specify multiple assemblies is either with multiple attributes or with multiple names in a single attribute:

> You can define multiple friend assemblies in two ways. They can appear
>   as individual assembly-level attributes ... [or they] can also appear
>   with separate InternalsVisibleToAttribute tags but a single assembly
>   keyword.

That is:

```
[assembly:InternalsVisibleTo("Friend1a")]
[assembly:InternalsVisibleTo("Friend1b")]
```

or:

```
[assembly:InternalsVisibleTo("Friend2a"), 
          InternalsVisibleTo("Friend2b")]
```

I don't think what you want is possible, and likely intentionally so. Making your internals visible to another assembly is something that should be used sparingly, since it allows more coupling than might otherwise be desirable. Thus it should difficult to show your internals unless you absolutely meant them to be shown to a given assembly. Wildcards actively works against that.

Your best option (if you don't want to use multiple attributes) is to either a) merge the assemblies so that they can just naturally share `internal`s or b) make certain key `internal` members `public` (or `protected`) and make those the integration points for the other assemblies.